# Calculating Integral using Fourier's transform

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}$ if $x > 0$, I calculated Fourier's transform of $f$, i.e. $F(\omega)$ and I got $F(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot(
1+i\omega)}$.

I am trying to find out how can I use this fact to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(2\omega)+\omega\sin(2\omega)}{1+\omega^2}d\omega$ but it seems That I am missing something?

Comment: Confused about why you think one solves the other, can you explain why you think so? And I'm sure there are easier ways to solve this integral.

Comment: @james.nixon we were asked to do it by this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$ \frac{e^{i\omega x}}{1+i\omega}=\frac{\cos(\omega x)+\omega \sin(\omega x)}{1+\omega^2}+i\, \frac{\sin(\omega x)-\omega \cos(\omega x)}{1+\omega^2}\tag 1$$

Note that the imaginary part of the right-hand side of $(1)$ is odd.

Comment: can we also use this ? first using FT of $e^{-a|t|}$ then Duality to obtain.. $$\frac{1}{1+t^2} \Leftrightarrow \pi \cdot e^{-|\omega|} $$ After this use $$\cos \omega t=\frac{e^{-j\omega_0 t}+e^{j\omega_0 t}}{2}$$ this will shift the FT to $\pm \omega_0$ then put $\omega=0$

Comment: And how will you handle $\omega \sin(\omega x)$?

Comment: From FT of $e^{-a|t|}\mathrm{sgn}(t)$ @Mark Viola